# How to get the result of json into the header

Tags: php

I just want to echo the result into the header location where it says url.
i tried alot of ways but, not success

Here is my code:

```
<?PHP
 $details1=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://2strok.com/download/download.json"));
 $details2=json_decode(file_get_contents($details1->data));
 echo "{$details2->data}";
 ?>

<?php header("Location: url"); ?>
```

Comment: Did you try `header("Location: {$details2->data}");` ???

Comment: Yes. not any respons :(

Comment: Take the time to go through some introductory PHP tutorials, read the documentation, and learn the basics.  If you start using more advanced functions without actually having any idea what you're doing, you're going to shoot yourself in the foot really quickly.

Comment: if it's that easy for you then why are u wasting your time to comment just solve it.  @PatrickQ 

I'm totally new in php YES. but try is for free :D

Comment: @john You should _show_ what you have tried and what didn't work. Please don't make us guess and go "I tried that, didn't work". That's a waste of your and our time.

Comment: @ModusTollens I just want to have the result of json into the header location.

i tried many was like
header("Location: ".$details2['data']);  
header("Location: {$details2->data}");
not any ansower :S

Comment: @ModusTollens I'm getting the blank white page. which should be the download url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like this?

```
<?PHP

 $details1=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://2strok.com/download/download.json"));
 $details2=json_decode(file_get_contents($details1->data));
 header("Location: ".$details2->data);
```

Comment: YES STILL NOT GIVING ME ANY RESULT :S

Comment: Don't yell @john, it's not nice.

Comment: @leopinzon blank white page :.

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry if you are felling bad of my question.

Comment: Did you check your error_log? -- check to not do any echo before the header function.

Comment: Also check to not leave any white spaces or line breaks before the header function, you can't write anything before sending a header

Comment: @leopinzon I've something like this :D

header("Location: "$details2['data']");

Comment: Just copied/paste your code to http://phpfiddle.org and it's works fine, there's something wrong from John side, why he's using two time <?php ?> ?

Comment: @john, just copy paste the code I sent you (each line), it should work just fine.

Comment: @leopinzon Thankyou it finally looks like it's working fine :D